# Simple Blazor approach to retrieving GeoLocation

Tags: geolocation, blazor

I wanted a simple method to retrieve Latitude and Longitude in Blazor without resorting to a library. After looking through various options, this was as simple as I could make it using a minimal amount of Javascript. Hopefully this is helpful to others.

The Component sends Javascript a callback function so we can make the call from the component then receive the answer to a known point. I show a busy spinner during the operation.

Answer (score 1):

```
    @inject IJSRuntime JS
    
    DotNetObjectReference<YourClassName> JsObjectReference = default!;

    bool _showGeolocationSpinner = false;

    
            private async Task GetLatitudeAndLongitude()
            {
                try
                {
                    _showGeolocationSpinner = true;
        
                    if (JsObjectReference == null)
                    {
                        JsObjectReference = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
                    }
        
                    await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("GetMyGeloLocation", JsObjectReference);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // display your error...
                }
            }
        
            [JSInvokable("ReceiveGeolocation")]
            public void GeolodationReceiver(GeoLocationResult data)
            {
                if (data != null)
                {
                    if (data.GeolocationErrorMessage.Length == 0)
                    {
                        _exposure.Latitude = data.lat;
                        _exposure.Longitude = data.lng;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // display your error...
                    }
                }
        
                _showGeolocationSpinner = false;
        
                StateHasChanged();
            }
        
    
            public void Dispose()
            {
                if (JsObjectReference != null)
                {
                    JsObjectReference.Dispose();
                }
        
                GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            }
        
        
        
        
        // Javascript - Requires HTTPS to work
        
        var dotNetObject;
        
        function GetMyGeloLocation(dotNetObjectReceiver) {
            dotNetObject = dotNetObjectReceiver;
        
            if (!navigator.geolocation) {
                var BrowserPermissions =
                {
                    lat: 0,
                    lng: 0,
                    GeolocationErrorMessage: 'Geolocation is not supported by your browser'
                };
        
                dotNetObject.invokeMethodAsync('ReceiveGeolocation', BrowserPermissions);
            }
            else {
                const options = {
                    enableHighAccuracy: true,
                    timeout: 5000,
                    maximumAge: 0
                };
        
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
            }
        }
        
        function success(position) {
            var BrowserPermissions =
            {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude,
                GeolocationErrorMessage: ""
            };
        
            dotNetObject.invokeMethodAsync('ReceiveGeolocation', BrowserPermissions);
        }
        
        function error(error) {
            var BrowserPermissions =
            {
                lat: latitude,
                lng: longitude,
                GeolocationErrorMessage: "Unable to retrieve location : " + error.message
            };
        
            dotNetObject.invokeMethodAsync('ReceiveGeolocation', BrowserPermissions);
        }
```